2015 RAM 5.7 automatic
2015 5,7 automatic transmission
I have cleaned all of the connections have a booster on the battery have checked all the fuses  and the starter connection nothing happens when I turn the key to start the truck nothing works nothing comes on
Now interior lights are flashing on and off and nothing happens when I turn the key

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you please edit your question and actually include a question? What are you trying to solve exactly?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
